# how to get total file size of queue not single file size in plupload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, plupload

How can i get total number of files size which are in queue. I want to allow user to upload only 100 mb file so now if any one selects a file greater than 100mb this code works good but when i choose 2 files of 60-60 mb than total is 120 mb and this will not show any error. any idea for the same

```
$(function() {
    $("#uploader").plupload({
        runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight',
        url : 'http://<?=$bucket?>.s3.amazonaws.com/',

        multipart: true,
        multipart_params: {
            'key': '<?=$filepath?>${filename}', // use filename as a key
            'Filename': '${filename}', // adding this to keep consistency across the runtimes
            'acl': 'public-read',
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'AWSAccessKeyId' : '<?=$accessKeyId?>',     
            'policy': '<?=$policy?>',
            'signature': '<?=$signature?>'
        },

        // optional, but better be specified directly
        file_data_name: 'file',
        filters : {
            // Maximum file size
            max_file_size : '100mb'
            // Specify what files to browse for
            //mime_types: [
            //  {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg"}
            //]
        },
        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : 'js/Moxie.swf',
        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : 'js/Moxie.xap'
    });

});
```

Comment: If you find the answer code is working, please mark it as correct answer so other can see that information. This code is working everyday in my production environments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/* Check the queue after files added to see if the total size of all files combined exceeds allowed limit. */
var maxQueueSize = 681574400; // Size in bytes. This is set to 650MB.
uploader.bind('QueueChanged', function(up) {
   if(uploader.total.size > maxQueueSize) {
      alert("Total size of all files exceeds disc capacity! Remove some files!");
   }
});
```

Found it here:
http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=757